# Adding up line totals for grand total with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm building a simple order form that calculates the line total for each product when the customer specifies the desired quantity.

I'm trying to have the form add (or subtract) the line total from a grand total as the customer changes the quantity.

**I'm calculating each line total here:**

```
$('#qtybox').change(function(){
    qty = $(this).val()
    if(qty < 10)
        $('#linetotal').text(qty * 925);
    else
       $('#linetotal').text(qty * 895);
 });

$('#qtybox1').change(function(){
    qty1 = $(this).val()
    if(qty1 < 10)
        $('#linetotal1').text(qty1 * 1045);
   else
      $('#linetotal1').text(qty1 * 1015);
});    

$('#qtybox2').change(function(){
    qty2 = $(this).val()
    if(qty2 < 10)
        $('#linetotal2').text(qty1 * 1045);
   else
      $('#linetotal2').text(qty1 * 1015);
});
```

But I'm stuck on how to add these up into a grand total and have it update as each quantity input field is taken out of focus. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your code a lot more readable and extensible by refactoring it. Adding classes to elements that have properties (like behavior and appearance) in common will make it easier to control things using a smaller number of functions. Check out [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wYZGq/) to see a working example. Here is the javascript component:

```
var BULK_CUTOFF = 10,
  REGULAR_PRICES = [985, 1045, 1045],
  BULK_PRICES = [925, 1015, 1015];

function getPrice(qty, idx) {
  if (isNaN(qty)) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (qty < BULK_CUTOFF) {
    return qty * REGULAR_PRICES[idx];
  }
  return qty * BULK_PRICES[idx];
}

function updateGrandTotal() {
  var total = 0;
  $('input.linetotal').each(function () {
    var value = parseInt($(this).val());
    if (!isNaN(value)) {
      total += value;
    }
  });
  $('#grandtotal').val(total);
}

$('input.qtybox').keyup(function () {
  var $this = $(this),
    idx = $this.index('input.qtybox'),
    qty = parseInt($this.val());
  $this.next('.linetotal').val(getPrice(qty, idx));
  updateGrandTotal();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. That makes a lot of sense. If I may ask you one thing, is there any reason you can think of why this wouldn't work within a table? Is it the .index()? If I remove one tag <table class="twelve"> which removes all of my table formatting it works beautifully. I really can't figure it out.

Comment: @Alex It all *could* work in a table, but as you suggest, it is likely that the argument supplied to `index()` (and possibly what goes on with `$this.next(...)` would need to be played with to get it working (since they both rely on the position of specific elements within the DOM). It's hard to say without seeing the html in question, though.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a line in the three functions (assuming that the grand total has id `grandtotal`):

`$('#grandtotal').text( $('#linetotal').val() + $('#linetotal1').val() + $('#linetotal2').val() )`

See the inclusion of the above line in your code:

```
$('#qtybox').change(function(){
    qty = $(this).val()
    if(qty < 10)
        $('#linetotal').text(qty * 925);
    else
       $('#linetotal').text(qty * 895);
    $('#grandtotal').text($('#linetotal').val() + $('#linetotal1').val() + $('#linetotal2').val() )

 });

$('#qtybox1').change(function(){
    qty1 = $(this).val()
    if(qty1 < 10)
        $('#linetotal1').text(qty1 * 1045);
   else
      $('#linetotal1').text(qty1 * 1015);
   $('#grandtotal').text($('#linetotal').val() + $('#linetotal1').val() + $('#linetotal2').val() )
});    

$('#qtybox2').change(function(){
    qty2 = $(this).val()
    if(qty2 < 10)
        $('#linetotal2').text(qty1 * 1045);
   else
      $('#linetotal2').text(qty1 * 1015);
    $('#grandtotal').text($('#linetotal').val() + $('#linetotal1').val() + $('#linetotal2').val() )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Umm I would suggest you to do it as follows:

1) create and assign id to the net total text box as you have done to all other input fields like qtybox,qtybox1 and so on..
set its initial value to 0
2) in the java script function where you calculate the price and using the id fields where you are reflecting the same on the HTML page their in that script itself simultaneously add these value to the value of your final total box and dynamically update its text as well as your doing for the other text boxes.. so it would be something like

after ur if else block

$('#id-of-your-total-box').text(value-of-qty1+value-of-total-box);

NB: these is a step by step suggestion from my end on how to do it.. 
all the best

Answer (score 0):

Put all the qtboxes i.e. 1,2,3 in a class and use .blur()  event to update grand total .Some thing like this

```
$('.qtbox').blur(function(){
var total=0;
$('.qtbox').each(total+$(this).val());
$('#grandtotal').text(total);
})
```